# Get HOSTNAME from a file in cloud-init

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I've the following file in my `cloud-init`

```
write_files:
- path: /opt/data/conf.conf
  owner: root:root
  permissions: '0755'
  content: |
    [default]
    host = $HOSTNAME
```

I need to interpolate properly the variable `$HOSTNAME` when it is executed in an EC2 instance.

I didn't find anything about that in the documentation but I found EC2 datasource.

Any idea how to properly interpolate that value?

The quick idea I had is to write it inside an executable and interpolate from there. is it the only way?